# Error when deserializing protobuf descriptor containing nested types

Tags: python, serialization, protocol-buffers

I need to send a protobuf descriptor to my server so that it can then be used to serialize/deserialize objects containing nested types. I wrote a quick example demonstrating my problem:

test.proto:

```
message A {
  message B {
    required string data = 1;
  }
  repeated B bs = 1;
}
```

test.py:

```
from descriptor_pb2 import DescriptorProto
from google.protobuf import descriptor,reflection,message

from test_pb2 import *

a = A()
b = a.bs.add()
b.data = "stuff"

d1 = a.DESCRIPTOR

dp1 = DescriptorProto()
d1.CopyToProto(dp1)

# dp1 serialized, sent over network, deserialized

d2 = descriptor.MakeDescriptor(dp1)

## This code fixes the problem
#for desc in dp1.nested_type:
#    d2.nested_types.append( descriptor.MakeDescriptor(desc) )
#d2.nested_types_by_name = dict((t.name, t) for t in d2.nested_types)
#    
#for f in dp1.field:
#    d2.fields_by_number[f.number].message_type = d2.nested_types_by_name[f.type_name.split('.')[-1]]
#
## This line cannot be run on the server side
#d2.fields[0].message_type._concrete_class = d1.fields[0].message_type._concrete_class 

reflection.ParseMessage(d1, a.SerializeToString())
reflection.ParseMessage(d2, a.SerializeToString())
```

When I run this code, I get an error on the last line:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 29, in <module>
    reflection.ParseMessage(d2, a.SerializeToString())
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\google\protobuf\reflection.py", line 168, in ParseMessage
    new_msg.ParseFromString(byte_str)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\google\protobuf\message.py", line 182, in ParseFromString
    self.MergeFromString(serialized)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\google\protobuf\internal\python_message.py", line 795, in MergeFromString
    if self._InternalParse(serialized, 0, length) != length:
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\google\protobuf\internal\python_message.py", line 827, in InternalParse
    pos = field_decoder(buffer, new_pos, end, self, field_dict)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\google\protobuf\internal\decoder.py", line 523, in DecodeRepeatedField
    if value.add()._InternalParse(buffer, pos, new_pos) != new_pos:
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\google\protobuf\internal\containers.py", line 216, in add
    new_element = self._message_descriptor._concrete_class(**kwargs)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_concrete_class'
```

I figured out that the error was occurring because descriptor.MakeDescriptor() does not fully copy all the nested types when it copies from the deserialized DescriptorProto, so I wrote the code in the comment block to compensate for it. However, the last line uses a reference to a class in the original descriptor, so I cannot do that on my server.

I've spent countless hours trying to figure this problem out, and it is a very crucial part of my system. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I would love to get in touch with with you regarding deserializing protobug bytearray. I am pretty much struggling myself. If you could kindly guide me, if there is something which helped you and share with me, it would be very helpful. Thanks